# Javascript external file functions won't work for me, were working before

Tags: javascript, html, function, external

First time posting so apologies in advance for any mistakes I make.
When I run this code in Chrome/Firefox I get the initial alert box asking to input a number. I enter a number and nothing happens. This was working before but when I came back to check the code for a similar issue I was having with another file it wouldn't open the second alert box.

**Task2.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src ="task2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var tempSelect = 0;

            while (tempSelect != 3) {
                tempSelect = prompt("1.Fahrenheit to Celcius\n2.Celcius to Fahrenheit\n3.To Exit");

                if (tempSelect == 1) {
                    Cel();
                }

                else if (tempSelect == 2) {
                    Fahr();
                }
            }

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Task2.js file**

```
  function Cel() {
    check = true;
    var fahr = prompt("Enter the degree in Fahrenheit to convert to Celcius");
    parseFloat(fahr);

    while (check == isNaN(fahr)) <!--isNaN  = is Not a number--><!--looping till a valid number is entered-->
    {
        alert("Enter a correct number!");
        fahr = prompt("Enter the degree in Fahrenheit to convert to Celcius");
    }

    var cel = ((5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32)); <!--calculations -->
    parseFloat(cel);
    alert("Fahr to Cel ===> " + cel); <!--Output-->
}

function Fahr() {
    check = true;
    var cel = prompt("Enter the degree in Celcius to convert to Fahrenheit");
    parseFloat(fahr);

    while (check == isNaN(cel)) {
        alert("Enter a correct number!");
        var cel = prompt("Enter the degree in Celcius to convert to Fahrenheit");
    }

    var fahr = (9.0 / 5.0 * cel) + 32;
    alert("Cel to Fahr ===> " + fahr);
}
```

Comment: I see a space between `src` and `=`

Comment: Any errors in the JS console? Also, `src ="something"` is not correct (extra space).

Comment: It is absolutely not an error to have a space in an HTML attribute clause around the `=`.

Comment: Are you sure that your "task2.js" file is being imported? Have you checked for errors in the developer console?

Comment: FWIW, [here's the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#after-attribute-name-state) for parsing HTML.  As @Pointy notes, and the spec shows, tabs, line feeds, form feeds and spaces are ignored.

Comment: Are the two files in the same directory? Is your filename correctly spelt?

Comment: Is your file really named "Task2.js"?  If so, case-sensitivity may be the problem (since your src is "task2.js")

Comment: both files are in the same folder, and i'm almost certain case doesn't come into it, i've changed the file name/script link regardless to match, still no joy

Comment: @BrendanDelaney Use the browser developer tool, and check console for the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! We all overlooked the obvious: you have HTML comments in your js file, which cause the javascript to fail.

Use `/* comment */`  or `// comment` instead of `<!-- comment -->` in javascript.

Comment: Take comfort that seven other developers (me included) failed to notice that in our first guesses in comments...

Comment: There is hope for me yet :D